# How to delete a file from the filesystem based on the returned case insensitive delta?

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am attempting to write a code to fulfill this particular case [documented](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-python-sdk-1.6-docs/index.html#dropbox.client.DropboxClient.delta) in the Dropbox Core API python SDK.

> [path, nil]: Indicates that there is no file/folder at the path on Dropbox. To update your local state to match, delete whatever is at path, including any children (you will sometimes also get “delete” delta entries for the children, but this is not guaranteed). If your local state doesn’t have anything at path, ignore this entry.

The API notes that the returned `[path]` is case insensitive.

> Remember: Dropbox treats file names in a case-insensitive but case-preserving way. To facilitate this, the path strings above are lower-cased versions of the actual path. The metadata dicts have the original, case-preserved path.

How do I remove the file or directory in question from my system if I do not know the case-preserved version of the path?

If it is relevant, my operating system in is Linux, although I hope to get a solution that will work on Windows as well if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to be able to recover the path with the original casing (e.g., for your local case sensitive file system) from the lower cased path, one solution is to keep a mapping of the lowered path to the original path client side. The specific implementation details are up to you, but any simple key value store would probably do the job.

Then, when you get one of these deletes, you can use this mapping to lookup the original path and process it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I was considering this method but wanted to find out if there was an easier way.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late but I just stumbled into the same problem and came up with a different solution. Maybe someone looking at this will prefer this method.

Since my API was solely going to be used on a linux server and since deletes would be comparatively a rare occurrence for me, I depended on the linux find command to help me.

```
    # LINUX ONLY
    cmd = "find {0} -iwholename '{1}'".format(basepath, caseInsensitivePath)
    with os.popen(cmd) as f:
        caseSensitivePath = f.read()[:-1] # -1 to remove the '\n'
        # error if more than 1 line
        if caseSensitivePath.find('\n') != -1:
            print "Found multiple results including: \n", caseSensitivePath
            msg = "[!]ERROR Could not delete {0}. Multiple case-sensitive results exist".format(caseInsensitivePath)
            raise Exception(msg)
        else:
            return caseSensitivePath
```

**basepath** is the base path of the find. I would recommend finding a way of using something more precise than root '/'. In my case I already had a list of paths in the sync folder so I was able to do a comparison as follows:

```
caseInsensitivePath = caseInsensitivePath.lower()
# find basepath
basepath = assets_root
for folder in self.myDict.keys():
    if caseInsensitivePath.lower().startswith(folder.lower()):
        basepath = folder
```

caseInsensitivePath is the pathname.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. It won't work for my case though because deletes are a common occurrence (it's a file sharing app after all) and making a system call every time definitely seems inefficient. +1 anyway. :)

Comment: How did you end up resolving it? did you make a sqlite or dbm file with the mapping?